# JQuery IF with multiple value show and hide element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, performance

I'm quite new with jquery, kindly need any of your assitance for my below question:

I have an input where users can type some ***number that less than 3 digit***, and have ***prefix start with "certain" number***, if condition is met, a specific element will be displayed, otherwise it will be hidden.

My problem is, if I have 10 or more of this condition, my code will be so long, and obviously decrease the performance.
Is there any simple way to achieve this ?

```js
$(function(c) {

    $('#check').on('keyup change', function(c) {
    var one = $('#check');
    if( (one.val() == 123) || (one.val() == 124) ) {
            $('#one').show();
        } else if (this.value.length < 3 ) {
            $('#one').hide();
        }
    }); 
    
    $('#check').on('keyup change', function(c) {
    var two = $('#check');
    if( (two.val() == 234) || (two.val() == 235) ) {
            $('#two').show();
        } else if (this.value.length < 3 ) {
            $('#two').hide();
        }
    });
    
        $('#check').on('keyup change', function(c) {
    var three = $('#check');
    if( (three.val() == 345) || (three.val() == 346) ) {
            $('#three').show();
        } else if (this.value.length < 3 ) {
            $('#three').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

```css
#one {
display: none;
}
#two {
display: none;
}
#three {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="check" maxlength="10">

<div id="one">
<br>
ONE
</div>

<div id="two">
<br>
TWO
</div>

<div id="three">
<br>
THREE
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
$('#check').on('keyup change', function(c) {

    //initially hide all
    if(this.value.length < 3){
        $('#three, #two, #one').hide();
    }
    else{

        switch(parseInt(this.value)){

            case 123: case 124: $('#one').show(); break;
            case 234: case 235: $('#two').show(); break;
            case 345: case 346: $('#three').show(); break;
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: perfect, I can't say anything but big thanks.
it's works perfectly as I expected.

Comment: This solution "stops trying", once the input string is longer than 3 characters. So, in case the user mistyped "126478" and then corrects the input by deleting the third character ("6") to "12478" nothing will show up. My solution would still present div "#one" again, see below.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible to simplify the OP code. Something like this.

```js
$(function() {//arg c is not used

    $('#check').on('keyup change', function() {//c is event object and is not used
    //note that 'c' from outer function is not 'c' in inner function
    //no need to re-request #check
    var one = $(this);//$('#check'); 
    $('#one, #two, #three').hide();//all in one
    if( (one.val() == 123) || (one.val() == 124) ) {
            $('#one').show();
            //optionnaly
            return;
        } 
    if( (one.val() == 234) || (one.val() == 235) ) {
            $('#two').show();
            //optionally
            return;
        } 
    if( (one.val() == 345) || (one.val() == 346) ) {
            $('#three').show();
        } 

    }); 
    
});
```

```css
#one {
display: none;
}
#two {
display: none;
}
#three {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="check" maxlength="10">

<div id="one">
<br>
ONE
</div>

<div id="two">
<br>
TWO
</div>

<div id="three">
<br>
THREE
</div>
```

Comment: Note that `$(function(c){...});` is a shortcut for `$(document).ready(function(c){...});` arg `c` is `load` event here and practically never used.

Comment: thanks, this code is very clear to me, but the result is not correct.
in your code, when type input more than 123 (lets say 12345), div one goes hidden again.
but i understand what you try to explain to me, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

**Less than 3 digit** or **equal to 3 digit**?

Your question and your code are confusing, but try this code:

**jQuery:**

```
$('#check').on('keyup change', function() {
    var val = $('#check').val();
    if ($.isNumeric(val) && val.length == 3) { //if value is numeric and contain 3 digits
        $('#one').toggle(val[0]=='1');   //show if first digit is 1 else hide
        $('#two').toggle(val[0]=='2');   //show if first digit is 2 else hide
        $('#three').toggle(val[0]=='3'); //show if first digit is 3 else hide
    } 
    else {
        $('#one,#two,#three').hide();   //hide them all
    }
});
```

**CSS:**

```
#one,
#two,
#three {
   display: none;
}
```

Good luck and keep learning! Please correct me if I misunderstand your question.

## UPDATE:

Seems this is what you need:

```
$('#check').on('keyup change', function() {
    var val = $('#check').val();
    var prf = val.substring(0,3);
    if ($.isNumeric(val) && val.length >= 3) { //if values is numeric and contain at least 3 digit
        $('#one').toggle(prf=='123'); //show if first 3 digits is '123' else hide
        $('#two').toggle(prf=='234'); //show if first 3 digits is '234' else hide
        $('#three').toggle(prf=='345'); //show if first 3 digits is '345' else hide
    } else {
        $('#one,#two,#three').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: i.m sorry if you had a confusing with my question.
i mean if user type 123 or more, only div one will show, or 234 or more only div two will show, if user type less than 3 digit, all div must stay hidden.
thanks anyway, and sure, i'll keep learning

Comment: @Andy no problem :) still bit confused, when you say "123 or more", is it like 124, 125, etc until 233 or you mean more digits like 12345?

Comment: i mean prefix, number that start with 123, and can be more, such as 1234567 or 1235745...
but the first 3 digit must met the condition (must 123)

Comment: @Andy I have updated my answer (see in bottom) :) try that and tell me if it's correct

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you want to type even less, you could do the following:

```js
$(function(c) {
 a=['one','two','three','four'];
 $('#check').on('keyup',function(){
  var cval=$('#check').val()
  a.forEach(function(id,i){
   var key=new RegExp('^'+(i+1)+(i+2)+'['+(i+3)+(i+4)+']');
   $('#'+id).toggle(key.test(cval))
  })
 })
});
```

```css
#one,#two,#three,#four { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="check" maxlength="10">

<div id="one">
<br>
ONE
</div>

<div id="two">
<br>
TWO
</div>

<div id="three">
<br>
THREE
</div>

<div id="four">
<br>
FOUR
</div>
```

By simply extending the array `a` you can even have a few more cases covered. But soon you will get into double digit numbers ... ;-)

Comment: Your code quite complex for a new like me, but thanks anyway.
however, your code result is not what i expect, 
i mean if user type 123 or more (1234567.... ) only div one will show, or if user type 234 or more, ony div two will show.
Your code above show all div.

Comment: @Andy, yes, of course! I agree, my code is probably "a bit of an overkill" - I just wanted to have a little fun playing around. The problem you mentioned with the longer inputs is fixed now (enclosing the regexp in `^` and `$`). Still - on a more serious note - I found that it is almost always worth investing some time in making your code as concise as possible. This will make later extensions and changes easier.

Comment: yes, you fixed show all div, but it still not correct, because when type more than 3 digit start with 123 (eg. 123456 ) the div one goes hidden again, it must stay displayed.

Comment: OK, also no problem. I did not know that that was your intention. I just removed the `$` again and now it should do what you expect.