# Using a flag variable to show/hide elements in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a form as shown on the image having a dropdownlist, 2 divs and 2 buttons that are shown / hidden based on some situations on every page load (on initial load and after data retrieving, etc.). On the other hand I use a single variable called `hasValue` in the Controller and based on each situation I set this variable in the Controller and get this on Ajax success in the razor View. Then on page load I make the components visible hidden as shown below:

[image]

***Controller:***

```
public ActionResult DemoMethod() 
{
    //code omitted    
    if (...)
    {
        return Json(new { success = true, hasValue = true });
    }
    return Json(new { success = true, hasValue = false });                
}
```

***View:***

```
<a id="btn-save" href="javascript:toggleField(false);"> Save </a>


<script>
    var hasValue = false;

    $(function () {
        //I set hasValue property retrieved from Controller via Ajax on the razor page load and use whenever I need in the View
        toggleField(hasValue);
    });

    function toggleField(param) {
        $('#div1').css('display', !param ? 'block' : 'none');
        $('#div2').css('display', param ? 'block' : 'none');
        $('#btn1').css('display', param ? 'block' : 'none');
        $('#btn2').css('display', !param  ? 'block' : 'none');
    }

</script>
```

My problem is that. In some situations, the single variable `hasValue` is not enough. In this case should I use an extra parameter besides `hasValue` variable in each field above?

I am not sure if there is a better way or elegant solution for this kind of situations.

Any helps would be appreciated.

Comment: Highly recommended to do `$("#btn-save").on("click",function(e) { e.preventDefault(); toggleField(false) })`

Comment: @mplungjan Sorry, I added the variable and necessary explanations. Thanks.

Comment: @mplungjan hasValue

Comment: Also please do `$('#div1').toggle(param)` and `$('#div2').toggle(!param)` instead of changing the CSS like that

Comment: But when or where should I call `$('#div1').toggle(param)`?

Comment: Like you are  now I guess

Comment: I understood but if I call `$("#btn-save").on("click",function(e) { e.preventDefault(); toggleField(false) })` how should I update `toggleField(){}` method? In this case I think I cannot use the same lines. On the other hand, I do not want show/hide based on the clicks, instead I use the results from the Controller (if theere is value display some elements, if not hide them, etc.). So, in the last situation, I am not sure if this is a proper way for me. Any idea?

Comment: @mplungjan Is the approach on [JQuery IF with multiple value show and hide element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087592/jquery-if-with-multiple-value-show-and-hide-element) good for me? I have really no idea for this scenario.

Comment: @mplungjan Any help pls?

Comment: @Anonymous Do you have any idea regarding to solution?

Comment: I don't quite get what you want. Could you pls list out all situations that you are expecting ? From this one, We can figure out whether we need extra params or not.

Comment: @Anonymous Yoıu can simply suggest an approach regarding to this situation. I need approach suggest rather than code.

Comment: I did not get your all  situations and expections, So it's hard for me to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think Jack means

```
function toggleField(param) {
        $('#div1').toggle(param);

        $('#div2').css('display', param ? 'block' : 'none');
        $('#btn1').css('display', param ? 'block' : 'none');
        $('#btn2').css('display', !param  ? 'block' : 'none');
    }
```

It's not helped by the image names not matching your code..

If you need to vars use two. Nothing wrong with that. Get it working then improve..